# How to download finstr package?

Tags: r, github, rstudio, finance

I am new to Rstudio and coding in general.
I am trying to download financial statements for analysis (From SEC/Edgar). I thought it would be a good idea to use the finstr package I found on Github:
https://github.com/bergant/finstr/blob/e4d13110a9bc687b618793ca209be1a0b241e668/readme.md

However, when I try to download the finstr package it doesn't work.

What am i doing wrong?

The code I have so far is: (copy pasted from github into Rstudio)

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("bergant/finstr")

library(XBRL)
# parse XBRL (Apple 10-K report)
xbrl_url2014 <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312514383437/aapl-20140927.xml"
xbrl_url2013 <- 
  "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312513416534/aapl-20130928.xml"
old_o <- options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
xbrl_data_aapl2014 <- xbrlDoAll(xbrl_url2014)
xbrl_data_aapl2013 <- xbrlDoAll(xbrl_url2013)
options(old_o)


library(finstr)

st2013 <- xbrl_get_statements(xbrl_data_aapl2013)
st2014 <- xbrl_get_statements(xbrl_data_aapl2014)
st2014
```

I get the following error for finstr:

"Error in library(finstr) : there is no package called ‘finstr"

Comment: I ran your first three lines exactly, and then library(finstr) and didn't get an error. Are there warnings or errors when you run install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("bergant/finstr")